# Choosing between Triticonazole and Tebuconazole for rose black spot

Tags: fungus, roses

It seems that only two systemic fungicide are still on the UK market sold for rose black spots being **Triticonazole** (*UK brand name: Fungus Clear Ultra - Scotts Company*) and **Tebuconazole** (*UK brand name: Bayer Garden Concentrated Fungus Fighter*)

Can anyone point me in the direction of any research that shows how there effectiveness compares with each other?

(At present I try to use both in year and need to spray my rose hedge every few weeks to keep it clear of black spot.)

Answer (score 2):

Neither product is massively effective, simply providing some control of the problem, and neither one is any better than the other, as far as I can tell in use. The one I usually recommend for roses is Roseclear Ultra, which is a combined preparation of an insecticide and a fungal treatment (triticonazole), so it deals with aphid infestation too. Can only be applied 4 times in a year, and should not be used while the bees are still working, if the flowers are open.

https://www.lovethegarden.com/products/pests-disease/roseclear-ultra

However, given you've got a hedge, where black spot is much more likely to occur anyway, and it's difficult to get a spray to reach all parts because of the 'thicket' like nature of the growth, then I'd suggest a natural, non harmful treatment for fungal infection, particularly black spot - cow's milk. Mix one part milk to two parts water in a sprayer, and spray till run off. And you can use that mix as often as you like or as necessary, without harming anything in the environment.... link below

http://www.agardenforthehouse.com/2012/05/got-black-spot-get-milk/

Comment: I only use Roseclear when I have an aphid problem, as I don't wish to use more "chemicals" then I need on my 110 foot rose hedge.

Comment: Well, the milk solution is ideal then...  with the occasional insecticide separately for insect pests, if you feel you must treat for those.

Comment: 10% solution didn't work for my mildew problem. Maybe next year I'll try 30-100% as per the comments in your link.

Comment: @GrahamChiu - supposed to be 1 to 9 for powdery mildew, and 1 to 2 for black spot - different conditions. And the milk treatment only works on powdery mildew - downy and other forms of mildew do not respond to this treatment.

Comment: Bamboo told me about this ratio for milk and water and believe me it works for powdery mildew.  Powdery mildew is the only fungus I know that can be controlled or 'cured' AFTER the fact the plant gets this fungus.  One fungal spore can innoculate the entire plant and the best fungicide is sort of a 'raincoat'.  Not allowing water to splash off the ground and onto the plant.  Please send pictures of your black spot on your hedge.  Sometimes it is beneficial just to relax about a few insects a few spots.  Completely normal and healthy plants can usually take care of this stuff all by themselves.